# Counting choices in Exam

Tags: counters, exam

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{environ}

\newtoks\allanswers

\NewEnviron{answer}
{%
 \edef\temp{%
   \the\allanswers % the previous ones
   \thequestion) \thechoice
   \noexpand\par % maybe \par has been redefined
   \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
 }
 \global\allanswers=\expandafter{\temp}
}

    \newcommand{\Cchoice}{\CorrectChoice\begin{answer}\end{answer}}
\newcommand{\showallanswers}{%
\ifprintanswers {\centering ANSWER KEYS \par} \textbf{\the\allanswers} \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question One
\begin{choices}
\Cchoice True
\choice False
\choice False
\choice False
\choice False
\end{choices}

\question Two
\begin{choices}
\choice False
\choice False
\Cchoice True
\choice False
\choice False
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\showallanswers
\end{document}
```

That I want output,

[image]

That is, I want all **true** choices counting.

Number of choice A's

Number of choice B's

Number of choice C's

Number of choice D's

Number of choice E's

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand this question! Do you want to count the total numbers of choice questions?

Comment: This means the result should be 10 in your given example?

Comment: @Özgür Your new edit is not what Christian was talking about though.

Comment: @Özgür: This is really annoying -- I asked you about that the output should be 10 -- you said 'yes', now you're changing the question completely! :-((((

Comment: @Özgür: All work useless :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `etoolbox`'s arithmetic with macro commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\newtoks\allanswers

\NewEnviron{answer}
{%
 \edef\temp{%
   \the\allanswers % the previous ones
   \thequestion) \thechoice
   \noexpand\par % maybe \par has been redefined
   \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
 }
 \global\allanswers=\expandafter{\temp}
 \csnumgdef{ctrchoice\thechoice}{\csname ctrchoice\thechoice\endcsname + 1} % Increments ctrchoice\thechoice if it is defined; sets it to one otherwise.
}

    \newcommand{\Cchoice}{\CorrectChoice\begin{answer}\end{answer}}
\newcommand{\showallanswers}{%
\ifprintanswers {\centering ANSWER KEYS \par} \textbf{\the\allanswers} \fi}


\newcommand{\showchoicecounts}[1]{% The argument is the number of choices
    \setcounter{choice}{0}
    \whiledo{\value{choice} < #1}{%
        \stepcounter{choice}%
        \csnumgdef{ctrchoice\thechoice}{\csname ctrchoice\thechoice\endcsname}% Set ctrchoice\thechoice to 0 if undefined
        % Edit the following line to do formatting
        \thechoice: \csname ctrchoice\thechoice\endcsname \newline}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question One
\begin{choices}
\Cchoice True
\choice False
\choice False
\choice False
\choice False
\end{choices}

\question Two
\begin{choices}
\choice False
\choice False
\Cchoice True
\choice False
\choice False
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\showallanswers


\showchoicecounts{5}
\end{document}
```