# How to create a specific problem with 5 choice options

Tags: exam

Does anyone know how is it possible to make such a question environment in a latex book without using exam class? [image]

Comment: A bit of context might be useful. Making the layout is relatively easy, but does it need the full capabilities of the `exam` class (showing/hiding solutions)?

Comment: I prefer to have all capabilities of the exam class, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Please consider providing some starting code (preferably a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) so we have a better idea what you are trying to do. (This is also what is meant by "context" in the above comment, I assume.) As for the centering of the last item, it looks similar to this question to me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371391/47927 .

Comment: @JasperHabicht Could you look at this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700511/generating-bubble-answer-sheet