# Generating bubble answer sheet

Tags: macros, environments, exam, renewcommand, exsheets

I wish to adding bubble answer sheet in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}
\usepackage{enumerate,tikz}

\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\squared{\arabic*}}
\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}
    
    \begin{question}
        Which of the following answers is correct for the given recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$?
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $O(n^2)$
            \item $O(n^3)$
            \item $O(n^4)$
            \item $O(n\log n)$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{question}
    
    \begin{solution}
        this is a solution
    \end{solution}
    \chapter{answer Sheet}
    
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

In more detail, I am writing a multiple choice book. I wish to add a bubble answer sheet to chapter Answer Sheet so that for each question mark correct choice like below image:

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219425/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-bubble-answer-sheet-for-multiple-choice-exam and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309359/multiple-choice-questions-with-xparse-package

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Unfortunately, I can't use those post to resolve my issue.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How it possible to use those in my MWE? Could you guide me?

Comment: The `exsheets` package is outdated. Are you ure you want to use it? Maybe give its successor `xsim` a try. Also, you should probably not load the `enumerate` package which is an outdated predecessor of `enumitem`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished without modifying exsheets.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}
\usepackage{enumerate,tikz}

\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\squared{\arabic*}}


\newcommand{\bubble}[1]% #1 is correct choice (out of 4)
{\bgroup
  \fboxsep=0pt
  \count1=0
  \count2=#1\relax
  \loop\ifnum\count1<4
    \advance\count1 by 1
    \ifnum\count1=\count2
      \fbox{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1em}{\baselineskip}}\quad
    \else
      \fbox{\makebox[1em]{\number\count1}\strut}\quad
    \fi
  \repeat
\egroup}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}
    
    \begin{question}
        Which of the following answers is correct for the given recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$?
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $O(n^2)$
            \item $O(n^3)$
            \item $O(n^4)$
            \item $O(n\log n)$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{question}
    
    \begin{solution}
        \bubble{3}
    \end{solution}
    \chapter{answer Sheet}
    
    \printsolutions
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I use Solution environment for complete solution of the problem. Could you use another environment? Thank you.

Comment: @tstt From the code you posted in your question, it is not clear how exactly you use the `solution` environment. At least, it is not clear to me.

Comment: The solution environment was an already solved problem.  Modifying or replaceing it is more difficult.